# perform logical or on sublist of a list efficiently

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, logic

Given a huge list `x` of `0`s and `1`s and an increasing list `i` of positions, which partitions `x` into (possibly empty) sublists, I wish to return a list, which has 1 if the corresponding sublist contains a 1, and 0 otherwise. In other words, perform logical 'or' on sublists.

The following code does what I want, but is somewhat inefficient:

```
n=10^9; AbsoluteTiming@MaxMemoryUsed[x=RandomChoice[{0,0,0,0,0,0,1},n];
i=Sort[{1}~Join~RandomInteger[{0,n},n/10]~Join~{n}]]
AbsoluteTiming@MaxMemoryUsed[y=TakeList[x,i[[2;;]]-i[[;;-2]]]]
AbsoluteTiming@MaxMemoryUsed[y=Clip[Plus@@#& /@y]]
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: The most expensive computation seems to be the last one and it can be sped up considerably using `Clip[Total /@ y]`.

Comment: @C.E. Actually, `Total` seems to be slower than `Plus`, with the same RAM load.

Comment: You could use : y =Boole[ Or[# == 1] & @@ y] instead of y=Clip[Plus@@#& /@y

Comment: @Leo OK, I did not check the RAM load, I did not know that was a problem.

Comment: `y = Unitize[Total[y, {2}]` (or `y = Clip[Total[y, {2}]`)  is a little slower but reduces MaxMemoryUsed.

Comment: Somewhat faster at the end: `bitor = Compile[{{ll, _Integer, 1}}, Max[ll, 0]];
AbsoluteTiming@MaxMemoryUsed[y4 = Map[bitor, y];]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just use [`Accumulate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Accumulate) on `x` and avoid creating the sublists (which is very slow because the sublists can't be packed). Your  version (with $n=10^8$ because I'm not patient):

```
n=10^8; AbsoluteTiming@MaxMemoryUsed[x=RandomChoice[{0,0,0,0,0,0,1},n];
i=Sort[{1}~Join~RandomInteger[{0,n},n/10]~Join~{n}]]
AbsoluteTiming@MaxMemoryUsed[y=TakeList[x,i[[2;;]]-i[[;;-2]]]]
AbsoluteTiming@MaxMemoryUsed[y=Clip[Plus@@#& /@y]]
```

> {2.35377, 1600000792}

> {4.43064, 2257877552}

> {18.8051, 640474752}

Using [`Accumulate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Accumulate) on `x` instead:

```
AbsoluteTiming @ MaxMemoryUsed[
    z = Clip @ Differences @ Prepend[0] @ Accumulate[x][[Rest@If[i[[1]]==0,i+1,i]-1]];
]
```

> {1.23973, 1040000832}

Check:

```
z == y
```

> True

Comment: For `x={0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1};  i={0,0,2,5,5,8,10,10};` your code returns errors. For some background, my data is `a=SparseArray[{0 and 1 entries},{dims}]; x=a["NonzeroValues"]; i=a["RowPointers"]`, hence `i` can have repeated elements between 0 and n. A fix is `Clip@Differences@Accumulate[{0}~Join~x][[i+1]]`, which is more efficient (CPU and RAM wise) than all previous suggestions. Thank you for this solution!